# getGoogleAppid failed/uploading is not possible Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-location

I have an app which takes the location and sends it to a server. I get the following errors which I have no idea from where they came from:

```
 11-05 02:47:11.699 27839-27839/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
11-05 02:47:11.699 27839-27839/? E/Zygote: v2
11-05 02:47:11.719 27839-27839/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-05 02:47:12.009 27839-27896/name.company.newapp E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-05 02:47:12.009 27839-27896/name.company.newapp E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

And here is the full logcat:

```
 11-05 02:47:11.699 27839-27839/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
11-05 02:47:11.699 27839-27839/? E/Zygote: v2
11-05 02:47:11.699 27839-27839/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10799
11-05 02:47:11.699 27839-27839/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
11-05 02:47:11.719 27839-27839/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-N9005_5.0 ver=27
11-05 02:47:11.719 27839-27839/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_5.0_0027
11-05 02:47:11.719 27839-27839/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-05 02:47:11.719 27839-27839/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-05 02:47:11.759 27839-27839/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
11-05 02:47:11.759 27839-27839/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
11-05 02:47:11.819 27839-27839/name.company.newapp D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/name.company.newapp-2/base.apk
11-05 02:47:11.989 27839-27896/name.company.newapp I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
11-05 02:47:12.009 27839-27896/name.company.newapp E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-05 02:47:12.009 27839-27896/name.company.newapp E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
11-05 02:47:12.189 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@c87f19b
11-05 02:47:12.189 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: 0 {
11-05 02:47:12.189 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object:    email=bb@gmail.com
11-05 02:47:12.189 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: }
11-05 02:47:12.189 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: <<<<<
11-05 02:47:12.189 27839-27839/name.company.newapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:name.company.newapp time:726092745
11-05 02:47:12.209 27839-27839/name.company.newapp D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-05 02:47:12.209 27839-27839/name.company.newapp D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@a9eedf8
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: 0 {
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object:    fname=D-B
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: }
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp V/Cursor Object: <<<<<
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp D/Activity: performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-05 02:47:12.269 27839-27839/name.company.newapp D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-05 02:47:12.289 27839-27901/name.company.newapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.025_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 11/19/14 Wed
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: mybranch5813579
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1_rb1.11
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.025 + 30e7589 +  NOTHING
11-05 02:47:12.339 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-05 02:47:12.369 27839-27901/name.company.newapp I/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xaf022088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8 
11-05 02:47:12.369 27839-27901/name.company.newapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
11-05 02:47:12.519 27839-27839/name.company.newapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@37fd12d1 time:726093077
```

I think I have all the necessary permissions.This is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="name.company.newapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name=".InternetRelated.NightAssetContentProvider"
            android:authorities="name.company.newapp.NightAssetContentProvider" >
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserActivities.Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserActivities.AfterLogin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_after_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UploadNewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_new"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @Yvette that s all of it

Comment: @Yvette I had a `finish()` somewhere. That's why the app was crashing. Now I still get the same errors but it's not crashing. I updated the logcat. Hope this will help you give me some information about those errors.

Comment: have someone figure this out?